# Java GUI repaint() problem?

Tags: java, user-interface, refresh, jpanel, repaint

I have a JFrame. This JFrame contains a JButton. I click the JButton and 10 JTextFields are created.

the problem:
I cannot see them until "I force a repaint()" by resizing the window. Only then do I see the JTextFields created.

CODE:

```
JPanel points = new JPanel();

//Creating the JTextFields:
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    points.add(textField);
}

repaint();
this.repaint();
super.repaint();
points.repaint();
```

---

THANK YOU - after the for loop, I just called points.validate() and it worked...

Comment: And you don't need to call repaint, since the validate will do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Container.add`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) API docs sayeth:

> Note: If a component has been added to
>   a container that has been displayed,
>   validate must be called on that
>   container to display the new
>   component. If multiple components are
>   being added, you can improve
>   efficiency by calling validate only
>   once, after all the components have
>   been added.

It's obscure and not very clever, but it's the rules. It may be better to call `JComponent.revalidate`

Comment: Also, make sure this alteration to the UI is done in the event dispatch thread.