# Java GUI repainting error?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, repaint

This one's a tough one - I have a JFrame that generates JTextFields. When I go from generating 2 JTextFields to 12 JTextfields (for example), I see some error where there is an extra differently-sized JTextField at the end. It seems to be a repaint error.

**Main.java code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static Display display = new Display();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        display.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Display.java code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JFrame {
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 820;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
    final int X_OFFSET = 40;
    final int Y_OFFSET = 40;

    final int GRAPH_OFFSETX = 35;
    final int GRAPH_OFFSETY = 60;
    final int GRAPH_WIDTH = 500;
    final int GRAPH_HEIGHT = 500;
    final int GRAPH_INTERVAL = 20;

    JButton submit;
    JTextField top;
    JTextField bottom;
    JTextField numPoint;
    JPanel bpanel;
    JPanel points;

    int maxPoints;

    public Display() {
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLocation(X_OFFSET, Y_OFFSET);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Geometric Transformations");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        top = new JTextField();    // parameter is size of input characters
        top.setText("1 2 3");
        top.setBounds(590, 150, 120, 25);

        bottom = new JTextField();    // parameter is size of input characters
        bottom.setText("5 6 7");
        bottom.setBounds(590, 200, 120, 25);

        numPoint = new JTextField();
        numPoint.setText("Number of Points?");
        numPoint.setBounds(550,200,200,25);
        this.add(numPoint);

        SubmitButton submit = new SubmitButton("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(570, 250, 170, 25);

        bpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));
        bpanel.add(top);
        bpanel.add(bottom);
        bpanel.add(submit);

        points = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        points.setBounds(540,250,265,60);
        this.add(points);

        bpanel.setBounds(550,100,200,70);
        this.add(bpanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        Component[] a = points.getComponents();
        System.out.println(a.length);
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(100, 100, 20, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        genGraph(g, GRAPH_OFFSETX, GRAPH_OFFSETY, GRAPH_WIDTH, GRAPH_HEIGHT, GRAPH_INTERVAL);
    }

    public void genGraph (Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height, int interval) {
        // draw background
        int border = 5;
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        width = width - (width % interval);
        height = height - (height % interval);
        for (int col=x; col <= x+width; col+=interval) {
            g.drawLine(col, y, col, y+height);
        }
        for (int row=y; row <= y+height; row+=interval) {
            g.drawLine(x, row, x+width, row);
        }
    }
    class SubmitButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

        public SubmitButton(String title){
            super(title);
            addActionListener(this);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            maxPoints = Integer.parseInt(numPoint.getText()) * 2;

            points.removeAll();

            for (int i=0; i<maxPoints; i++) {
                JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                points.add(textField);
            }
            points.validate();        // necessary when adding components to a JPanel
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369823/java-gui-repaint-problem-solved
            // What to Check:
            // Things between commas are either spaces (which will be stripped later)
            // or numbers!

            // Pairs must match up!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I put "2" in the "number of points" field and press submit and then change it to "12" and press submit nothing seems wrong (no extra differently sized JTextField)....can you expand on your error maybe with a screen shot?

Comment: The answer I marked solved the problem but basically when I go from entering something like 2 to 12, the 12 textfields are drawn except on the right there's a textfield (nonclickable) that has been drawn directly over.
only a problem in windows/mac (I forgot which one >< but only on 1 OS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new components are redrawn over the previous ones.
I added `points.repaint();` after `points.validate();` and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2):

Note: I was annoyed with the issue of repainting of the grid too (put the window in front then back, you will see).
From a quick search, it seems better to avoid painting directly on the JFrame, but instead delegate that to a sub-component. If I am wrong, somebody tell me.
Here is my solution (imperfect, I leave to you the task to improve it... :-P

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SODisplay extends JFrame {
    final int FRAME_WIDTH = 820;
    final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
    final int X_OFFSET = 40;
    final int Y_OFFSET = 40;

    JButton submit;
    JTextField top;
    JTextField bottom;
    JTextField numPoint;
    JPanel bpanel;
    JPanel points;
    GridPanel grid;

    int maxPoints;

    public SODisplay() {
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setLocation(X_OFFSET, Y_OFFSET);
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setTitle("Geometric Transformations");
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        grid = new GridPanel();
        grid.setBounds(0,0,530,FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.add(grid);

        top = new JTextField();    // parameter is size of input characters
        top.setText("1 2 3");
        top.setBounds(590, 150, 120, 25);

        bottom = new JTextField();    // parameter is size of input characters
        bottom.setText("5 6 7");
        bottom.setBounds(590, 200, 120, 25);

        numPoint = new JTextField();
        numPoint.setText("Number of Points?");
        numPoint.setBounds(550,200,200,25);
        this.add(numPoint);

        SubmitButton submit = new SubmitButton("Submit");
        submit.setBounds(570, 250, 170, 25);

        bpanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,3));
        bpanel.add(top);
        bpanel.add(bottom);
        bpanel.add(submit);

        points = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        points.setBounds(540,250,265,60);
        this.add(points);

        bpanel.setBounds(550,100,200,70);
        this.add(bpanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        Component[] a = points.getComponents();
        System.out.println(a.length);
        repaint();
    }

    class SubmitButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

        public SubmitButton(String title){
            super(title);
            addActionListener(this);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            maxPoints = Integer.parseInt(numPoint.getText()) * 2;

            points.removeAll();

            for (int i=0; i<maxPoints; i++) {
                JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                points.add(textField);
            }
            points.validate();        // necessary when adding components to a JPanel
            points.repaint();
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369823/java-gui-repaint-problem-solved
            // What to Check:
            // Things between commas are either spaces (which will be stripped later)
            // or numbers!

            // Pairs must match up!
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                SODisplay display = new SODisplay();
                display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                display.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class GridPanel extends JPanel {
        // Or drop the offset and adjust the placement of the component
        final int GRAPH_OFFSETX = 35;
        final int GRAPH_OFFSETY = 60;
        final int GRAPH_WIDTH = 500;
        final int GRAPH_HEIGHT = 500;
        final int GRAPH_INTERVAL = 20;

        public GridPanel() {
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(100, 100, 20, 30);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            genGraph(g, GRAPH_OFFSETX, GRAPH_OFFSETY, GRAPH_WIDTH, GRAPH_HEIGHT, GRAPH_INTERVAL);
        }

        public void genGraph (Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height, int interval) {
            // draw background
            int border = 5;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            width = width - (width % interval);
            height = height - (height % interval);
            for (int col=x; col <= x+width; col+=interval) {
                g.drawLine(col, y, col, y+height);
            }
            for (int row=y; row <= y+height; row+=interval) {
                g.drawLine(x, row, x+width, row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's just my test code in one file for simplicity, you might want to dissect it differently, of course.