# repaint() in Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, validation, repaint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java GUI repaint() problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369823/java-gui-repaint-problem)

I write a Java code, but I have a trouble with GUI problem. When I add a component into JFrame object, then I call repaint() method in order to update the GUI but it doesn't work. But when I minimize or resize this frame, the GUI is updated.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(460, 500);
    frame.setTitle("Circles generator");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setVisible(true);

    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter n:");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(input);

    CircleComponent component = new CircleComponent(n);
    frame.add(component);
    component.repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you added `JComponent` to already visible Container, then you have call

```
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

for example

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(460, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Circles generator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              frame.setVisible(true);
           }
        });

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter n:");
        CustomComponents0 component = new CustomComponents0();
        frame.add(component);
        frame.getContentPane().validate();
        frame.getContentPane().repaint();
    }

    static class CustomComponents0 extends JLabel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int margin = 10;
            Dimension dim = getSize();
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a good approach.   Regards

Comment: Now make sure the code in the main method runs on the EDT and it would even be better

Comment: @Robin you are right, thanks for notice

Comment: Does it change anything to use `revalidate()` instead?

Answer (score 5):

Simply write :

```
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

That will do .

Regards

Comment: right, there no reason to declare for ContentPane +1

Comment: @mKorbel : I was late for the answer, but your answer using ContentPane(), i guess is much better. Some say it's a good practise. But thankx for the points.  Regards

Answer (score 3):

You're doing things in the wrong order.

You need to first add *all* JComponents to the JFrame, and only then call `pack()` and then `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame

If you later added JComponents that could change the GUI's size you will need to call `pack()` again, and then `repaint()` on the JFrame after doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to call `frame.repaint()` as well to force the frame to actually redraw itself. I've had issues before where I tried to repaint a component and it wasn't updating what was displayed until the parent's repaint() method was called.

Comment: I change component.repaint() to frame.repaint(), but it doesn't work.