# Java Set Icon to button

Tags: java, button, icons

I really need help with probably so simple bug. I'm trying to load icon on my button but with some reason it keeps showing me just regular button. Here is how i tried so can anybody say me where i'm making it wrong.

```
buttonList[i]= new JButton();
        buttonList[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\img\\icon.bmp"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, and someone correct me if I am, but I believe that the supported file types for `ImageIcon` are JPEG, GIF, and PNG. So the error would be that your icon is a `.bmp` file.

The easiest way to change that would be to load it into MSPaint, and just click `Save As` and change the file type to either `JPEG` or `PNG`.

Comment: Thx for answer but that didnt help me, tried with jpeg and getting same thing. Just a regular button shows

Answer (score 0):

From [ImageIcon()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29)

"When specifying a path, use the Internet-standard forward-slash ("/") as a separator. (The string is converted to an URL, so the forward-slash works on all systems.) For example, specify:"

```
new ImageIcon("images/myImage.gif")
```

This may not be the problem, but it would be preferable.
Perhaps you need to [repaint()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853397/repaint-in-java).